# HTML 5 video tag does not display video

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
            <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/ mp4">
            <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
            <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
                <embed width="320" height="240" src="movie.swf">
            </object>
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make it work but it did not work. I am using ie 8 and firefox to test.

Comment: Please describe how it "did not work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/ mp4">
```

should be

```
 <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

you have extra space